# Division causes unbalanced parentheses

Tags: assembly, x86, att

In GNU `as` (the GNU assembler), the following code assembles without error:

```
mov $(80 * 24 + 4), %cx
```

However, this code does not:

```
mov $(80 * 24 / 4), %cx
```

Emitting the highly unexpected error:

```
example.S: Assembler messages:
example.S:42: Error: unbalanced parenthesis in operand 1.
```

The only difference is that the latter uses division, instead of addition. This should be valid, [according to the manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Infix-Ops.html#Infix-Ops).

(`$<expression>` embeds an immediate into the assembled output; i.e., a constant. The arithmetic is performed at "compile-time". I could work out the math, but it makes more sense in its expanded form.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/` signifies the start of a comment, in my particular case.

> `--divide`
>
> On SVR4-derived platforms, the character `/` is treated as a comment character, which means that it cannot be used in expressions. The `--divide` option turns `/` into a normal character.  This does not disable `/` at the beginning of a line starting a comment, or affect using # for starting a comment.

[This post on the binutils mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-binutils/2005-02/msg00054.html) also suggests a similar story:

> For compatibility with other assemblers, '`/`' starts a comment on the
>   i386-elf target.  So you can't use division.  If you configure for
>   i386-linux (or any of the bsds, or netware), you won't have this
>   problem.

I happen to be assembling for the `x86_64-elf` target, which I presume is sufficiently similar to the mentioned `i386-elf` (the former is for the `amd64` or "`x86_64`" arch, the latter is the same but for the older 32-bit x86 architecture).